# ASP.NET MVC URLs in a JSON request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

> **Warning:** The question refers to the RC version of ASP.net MVC.
>   Problem is solved in ASP.net MVC 1.0

I have a page that requests some JSON from an Action on my controller and then fills a table with that data. In my JSON reponse, I'm including an anon object that contains some fields. One of those fields is a URL to another controller/action. I am setting the URL using Url.Action in my controller.

The problem is that the link that comes out is not valid (due to context I guess). For instance, the "hosting" page URL looks like this:

```
/Challenges/Detail/4/HEADLINE which is {controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}
```

The URL in my json request calls the Profile action on my Account Controller. The URL should be something like this:

```
/Profile/username
```

However, it comes out as

```
../Profile/username
```

which resolves to

```
/Challenges/Detail/4/Profile/username
```

I'd like to avoid hardcoding any links if at all possible. What are my options here?

Answer (score 2):

Craig Stuntz answered this yesterday but his answer disappeared. He was correct, that I needed to install the ASP.NET MVC RC Refresh